# build libav from GIT using --enable-*

Tags: compiling, codecs, conversion, libav

I need to get a newer version of `libav-tools` (containing `avconv`) to get the AAC-encoder to resample an input 6-channel audio stream into an output 2-channel one.

I successfully built the package, but I realized after that I needed to `./configure --enable-libvo-aacenc` to get `avconv`to use AAC as an encoder. Here's what I'm trying to do :

```
git clone git://git.libav.org/libav.git
sudo apt-get build-dep libav-tools
cd libav
./configure --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
make
sudo make install
```

But I have this instead :

[image: configure&make]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here... I can't seem to use the libraries that are installed on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the VisualOn AAC encoder library (development files):

```
sudo apt-get install libvo-aacenc-dev
```